I am trying to load the kernel and display the messages from kernel when it is loaded successfully
My bootloader is loading the kernel successfully, but it is not displaying the messages from the kernel.
boot.asm snippet, when input is given 1 or 2, boot_mode is selected.
check_input:
    inc dh
    mov dl, 0x2              ; setting column for center pos
    call set_cursor_position
    cmp byte [si], '1'
    je normal_mode_1
    cmp byte [si], '2'
    je recovery_mode

    ; If input is neither 1 nor 2
    mov si, wrong_choice_msg
    call print_string
    jmp input_1

normal_mode:
    mov dh, bh
    inc dh
    mov dl, 0x2              ; setting column for center pos
    call set_cursor_position
    call clear_row
normal_mode_1:
    mov word [boot_mode], 1  ; Set boot mode to normal
    jmp load_kernel

recovery_mode:
    mov word [boot_mode], 2  ; Set boot mode to recovery
    jmp load_kernel

load_kernel:
    ; Load the kernel (it's at sector 2)
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, 0x1000           ; Load address

    mov ah, 0x02             ; BIOS read sectors function
    mov al, 1                ; Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0                ; Cylinder number
    mov cl, 2                ; Sector number (starting from 1)
    mov dh, 0                ; Head number
    mov dl, 0x80             ; Drive number (0x80 = first hard drive)
    int 0x13                 ; BIOS disk interrupt
    jc disk_error            ; Jump if there was an error

    ; pass boot mode to kernel
    mov ax, [boot_mode]
    mov [0x1000], ax

    ; jump to the kernel entry point
    jmp 0x0000:0x1000

disk_error:
    mov si, disk_error_msg
    call print_string
    jmp $


kernel.c
void print_string(const char *str) {
    unsigned short *video_memory = (unsigned short *)0xB8000;
    while (*str) {
        *video_memory++ = (*str++ | 0x0700); 
    }
}

void kernel_main() {
    unsigned short *boot_mode = (unsigned short *)0x1000;

    if (*boot_mode == 1) {
        const char *message = "Normal Mode";
        print_string(message);
    } else if (*boot_mode == 2) {
        const char *message = "Recovery Mode";
        print_string(message);
    } 

    while (1) {
        asm("hlt");
    }
}

I tried to debug it, but couldn't get ahead of it.
I am also attaching makefile
    nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-pic -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary -e _start kernel.o -o kernel.bin
    cat boot.bin kernel.bin  > disk.bin


